# ViewModel for meetings and rentals

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin

I am bringing up to date an old Xamarin app. I am concerned mostly with any design patterns I should be using or anti-patterns I shouldn't be using. This is my first attempt creating a `ViewModel` from scratch.

```
public sealed class DetailsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region Private Fields

    private ActivityDto _meeting;

    #endregion Private Fields

    #region Public Constructors

    public DetailsViewModel()
    {
        Meeting = new ActivityDto();
    }

    #endregion Public Constructors

    #region Public Events

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion Public Events

    #region Public Properties

    public string ActivityStatus
    {
        get => _meeting?.Activity_Status;
        set
        {
            if (value == _meeting.Activity_Status) return;
            _meeting.Activity_Status = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsComplete));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsScheduled));
        }
    }

    public string ActivityType
    {
        get => _meeting.Activity_Type;
        set
        {
            if (value == _meeting.Activity_Type) return;
            _meeting.Activity_Type = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRental));
        }
    }

    public string ContactCode
    {
        get => _meeting.ContactCode;
        set
        {
            if (value == _meeting.ContactCode) return;
            _meeting.ContactCode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get => _meeting.End_Date;
        set
        {
            if (value == _meeting.End_Date) return;
            _meeting.End_Date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool IsComplete => ActivityStatus == "Completed";

    public bool IsRental => _meeting?.Activity_Type == "Rental";

    public bool IsScheduled => ActivityStatus == "Scheduled";

    public string Location
    {
        get => _meeting.Location;
        set
        {
            if (value == _meeting.Location) return;
            _meeting.Location = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Notes
    {
        get => _meeting.ResolutionOverrideText;
        set
        {
            if (value == _meeting.ResolutionOverrideText) return;
            _meeting.ResolutionOverrideText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string SerialNumber
    {
        get => _meeting.SerialNumber;
        set
        {
            if (value == _meeting.SerialNumber) return;
            _meeting.SerialNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get => _meeting.Start_Date;
        set
        {
            if (value == _meeting.Start_Date) return;
            _meeting.Start_Date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #endregion Public Properties

    #region Private Properties

    private ActivityDto Meeting
    {
        get => _meeting;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _meeting)) return;
            _meeting = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ActivityStatus));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ContactCode));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Location));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Notes));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SerialNumber));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ActivityType));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StartDate));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EndDate));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsComplete));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRental));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsScheduled));
        }
    }

    #endregion Private Properties

    #region Public Methods

    public async Task GetMeetingAsync(int meetingId)
    {
        var options = new RestClientOptions(UserSettings.Url)
        {
            RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true
        };

        using (var client = new RestClient(options))
        {
            const string uri = "data/activity/{meetingId}/";

            var request = new RestRequest(uri)
                .AddUrlSegment("meetingId", meetingId);

            var response = await client.GetAsync<ActivityDto>(request);

            Meeting = response;
        }
    }

    #endregion Public Methods

    #region Protected Methods

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion Protected Methods

}
```

Any hints or tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the `ActivityDto` is using inconsistent naming: `Activity_Type`, `ContactCode`, `End_Date`, `ResolutionOverrideText`, etc.?

Comment: @PeterCsala Well in the Rest API EntityFramework is reading from existing model. I cannot change the fieldname and I didn't much want to to do property name mapping.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why do you use null conditional operator inside the `ActivityStatus`'s getter and nowhere else? Your API is quite error prone, since you can't enforce to call `GetMeetingAsync` before accessing any property.

Comment: @PeterCsala This is mostly trial and error for me. Before I set in the constructor `Meeting` to a `new ActivityDto` I was getting a Null error and I put that in there trying to diagnose the problem. I just haven't removed it.

Comment: Still you get `NullReferenceException` if you want to access `ContactCode` after initializing a new instance (and not calling the `GetMeetingAsync` method)

Comment: @PeterCsala No, putting the empty Meeting in the constructor fixed that.

Comment: Ohh, you are right. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a good solution for me.

I have only just one concern but it is not that objective. I personally don't like the usage of `#region` because it can fool you by saying that the class is not so big if all regions are collapsed.

It can also become outdated easily. Like in your case the your `OnPropertyChanged` method is `private`, but the region says `protected`.

I rather prefer the usage of `partial` classes. Like :

- `DetailsViewModel.PublicProperties.cs`
- `DetailsViewModel.NonPublicMembers.cs`

Or name them whatever you like :)

Comment: +1 also,  `preprocessor directives` is a language specific, and not OOP. while `partial` is. one of best open-source projects using `partial class` I've seen  is `Dapper`, it's a good reference though. (just some helpful info for other readers)